# perl qr to quote regex behaving differently

Tags: regex, perl

Here's my code:

```
my $orderId = "1610209";
$pdfFilename = "1610209_1.pdf";
my $re = qr/^${orderId}_/;
print Dumper($re);

if($pdfFilename =~ $re) {
    print "matched";
}
```

It' not matching!!
Dumper prints: $VAR1 = qr/(?^:^1610209_)/;

What could be wrong?
My environment:

perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

lsb_release -a

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Comment: Works fine for me using Perl 5.22.1 on Linux. Dumps `$VAR1 = qr/^1610209_/;` and prints out `matched`.

Comment: Can you please show the exact code you ran by copy-and-pasting the entire script verbatim, without changing it? I get a syntax error when I run what you've shown ("Undefined subroutine &main::Dumper"). When I fix that, it prints "matched"; maybe you didn't notice it because it appears right before the prompt, with no space (e.g. `matchedfoo$` if your prompt is `foo$`).

Answer (score 1):

Works For Me!™

Are you on Windows? That final print my not be displayed because STDOUT (ie. printing to the screen) is often line-buffered. That means it doesn't display until it sees a newline. If that's the final line of your program it might never display before the window closes.

Try `print "matched\n";` instead.

For more info, read [Suffering From Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my $orderId = "1610209";
my $pdfFilename = "1610209_1.pdf";
my $re = qr/^${orderId}_/;

if($pdfFilename =~ $re) {
print "matched Dumper($re)\n";
} else {
print "not matched Dumper ($re)\n";
}
```

which returns

```
matched Dumper((?^:^1610209))
```

however, why use data dumper?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $orderId = "1610209";
my $pdfFilename = "1610209_1.pdf";
if($pdfFilename =~ /^$orderId/) {
    print "Matched $orderId with $pdfFilename\n";
} else {
    print "Not Matched $orderId with $pdfFilename\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code matches. If you've found otherwise, that's not the program you ran.

---

Are you sure you don't actually have the following?

```
my $orderId = "1610209\n";
```

`chomp` lines you read from files to remove trailing newlines.